# Getting balloonevalterm to work (terminal version)

Tags: terminal, functions

I'm trying to get `balloonevalterm` to work in the terminal version of vim, but for some reason it does not yet work. Here's my `macros.vim` file:

```
function! MyBalloonExpr()
  let macros = {
  \ 'MACRO' : "MACRO\ndo { something(); } while (0)",
  \ }
  return get(macros, v:beval_text, '')
endfunction
set bexpr=MyBalloonExpr()
set ballooneval
set balloonevalterm
```

When I source this file with `:so %` in gvim, all is fine: when I place the mouse pointer over `MACRO` the balloon `MACRO  do { something(); } while (0)` appears. Sweet!

However, I can't get the balloon to appear in the terminal version of vim, even though `set balloonevalterm` should do so, according to my understanding.

I'm using vim 8.0.1427 in an XTerm(330), `TERM=xterm-256color` on FreeBSD and `:ver` shows it is compiled with `+ballon_eval` and `+balloon_eval_term`. What am I missing?

Comment: I can reproduce it with GTK2 Gui.

Comment: @Naumann You mean the balloon is shown in the GUI version but not in the terminal version?

Comment: yes. It is shown in the gui. I should have made this clear. vim 8.0.1417 here.

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2481)

Comment: This can be explained by the issue I raised here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2481 i.e. balloonevalterm is only functional when the content is provided asynchronously.

Comment: @puremourning, but if [#2481](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2481) was addressed and closed, why doesn't this example work? Or, if I've misunderstood, isn't the balloon meant to come up when moving the cursor on the word MACRO (whereas in gvim it does appear when hovering with the mouse on the word MACRO)?

Comment: I literally wrote a page of answer but my answer was turned into a comment and the actual answer deleted, so I have no interest in helping users on stack exchange if my work is to be treated like that by the moderators. Please use vim's actual support channels.